# Half-space in regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am supposed to write a little program that takes in a Persian text and in some places changes the space to half-space. The half-space or a [zero-width non-joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) is used in some languages to avoid a [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) when normalizing a text. It's unicode character is supposedly `'\u200c'` and in some text-editors it can be shown on the screen with a SHIFT+SPACE:

```
import re
txt  = input('Please enter a Persian text: ')
original_pattern = r'\b(\w+)\s*(ها|هايي|هايم|هاي)\b'
new_pattern = r'\1 \2'
new_txt = re.sub (original_pattern, new_pattern, txt)
print (new_txt)
```

In the code above, `new_pattern` is supposed to introduce a half-space between `\1` and `\2`, currently there is a space between them.

The question is: How can I put a half-space there? I tried the following and in both cases got a syntax error:

```
new_pattern = ur'\1\u200c\2'   

new_pattern = r'\1\u200c\2'
```

By the way, although in the Wikipedia article the unicode character for ZWNJ is given as U+200c, it doesn't seem to be working that way in the python shell and it is actually doubling the space:

```
>>> print ('He is a',u'\u200c','boy')
He is a ‌ boy

>>> print ("کتاب",u"\u200c","ها")
کتاب ‌ ها

>>> print ("کتاب ها")
کتاب ها
>>>
```

Comment: What version of Python? 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python adds a separator for arguments of print function, you can control this with [`sep` argument](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), try

```
print ('He is a', '\u200c', 'boy', sep="")
```

For a pattern, try

```
new_pattern = '\\1\u200c\\2'
```

or

```
new_pattern = '\\1\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}\\2'
```

reason is that when you add an `r` prefix, escapes `\` are ignored, so  `\u200c` part of pattern is threated as 5 charactes string, i.e. pattern equals `\\1\\u200c\\2`, hence your error.